# Android SQLite cursor null

Tags: android, image, sqlite, pdf, select

I'm dynamically creating a PDF file using iText library. In the PDF file I insert a picture taken from the database, but if the image is not present the file is not created. Is there a way around this thing when the cursor results is null?
This is my query:

```
String sql2  = "SELECT logo FROM logoa";
        Cursor c3 = db.rawQuery(sql2, null);
        if (c3.moveToFirst()) {         
            byte[] blob = c3.getBlob(c3.getColumnIndex(LogoTable.LOGO));

            Bitmap b1=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(blob, 0, blob.length);
 }
c3.close();
db.close;
...
```

A part of my Helper class

```
            @Override
            public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
                DatabaseHelper.db = db;

                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            //tabella logo
            builder = new StringBuilder();
            builder.append("CREATE TABLE {0} (");
            builder.append("{1} INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,");
            builder.append("{2} BLOB NOT NULL");
            builder.append(");");

            db.execSQL(MessageFormat.format(builder.toString(),
                     LogoTable.TABLE_NAME, 
                     LogoTable._ID,
                     LogoTable.LOGO));
```

Comment: Show your DB Helper class

Comment: Did you checked if your database file was created successfully? And if your logoa table is not empty?

Comment: The problem is likely to be the code that is trying to use `b1`.

Comment: @CL maybe it is as you say. The Code search `b1`, but if it is not present, does not continue. how can I do this always continue?

Comment: Are you aware that you are asking question about code that you have not shown?